# What is subsampling?

Tags: sampling, subsampling

The sample I have is constituted of 100 subsamples. In addition, each subsample is nationally representative and preserves any stratification of the sample from which it is drawn.

What does this mean? E.g. I want to make a representative sample of fish in the lake.

Comment: What do fish in a lake have to do with a "nationally representative sample"? In any case, a similar question was answered on Statalist recently.  See: http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1326724-setting-up-survey-design-with-svyset

Comment: Great, it helped! The fish has nothing to do with a nationally represrntative sample, the intention was to suggest a simple example to explain the terms subsample and representative :-)